# How do I make a color gradient in html text?

Tags: html, css

I'm extremely new to coding and I wanna ask, how do I make a text color gradient like the one shown in the picture?

[Here's The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G4Eh.png)

And also, can someone tell me what is the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **gradient**

Source: https://cssgradient.io/blog/css-gradient-text/

Source: https://fossheim.io/writing/posts/css-text-gradient/

Comment: @Cynamical This one too: https://fossheim.io/writing/posts/css-text-gradient/

Comment: How do I rotate the gradient? Like make it go left to right or right to left?

Comment: `#grad {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, yellow);
}`  you can use this for to direction the color

Comment: How do I integrate this into my code? 

``h1 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#57c7ff, #ffffff);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}``

Comment: And also can someone tell me the font of the image please?

Answer (score 0):

To find the font from the image, you can use a font predictor extension that you can get on Firefox, Chrome and others. Even just plain websites can find the font.